# C++ Auto Keyword - Float vs Int Trouble

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I'm relatively new to C++. I just read about the auto keyword in regards to type deduction. I've tried implementing this in a couple functions only to find that it was causing all of kinds of issues when working with math operators. I believe what was happening was that my functions started implementing integer division when I actually needed float division (variables 'i' and 'avg'). I posted the code using the auto keywords below.

Now when I explicitly declared the variables as floats, the function worked fine.

So is this an example in which using auto would not be preferred? However, I can definitely see that they would help when generating the iterators.

```
namespace Probability
{
        /* ExpectedValueDataSet - Calculates the expected value of a data set */
        template <typename T, std::size_t N>
        double ExpectedValueDataSet(const std::array<T, N>& data)
        {
            auto i = 0;
            auto avg = 0;

            for(auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
            {
                i = it - data.begin() + 1;
                avg = ((i-1)/i)*avg + (*it)/i;
            }

            std::cout << avg << " \n";
            return avg;
        }

};
```

Comment: Write `avg = 0.0` instead and change `avg = ((i-1)/i)*avg + ...` to `avg = ((i-1)*avg/i) + ...`

Comment: **auto** is a storage class - variables stored in stack, value lost when function returns - you need a type specifier as well, since avg obtained by division **auto float avg = 0;** will work fine.

Comment: @ArifBurhan That changed in C++11. The usage of `auto i = 0;` is completely valid today - although it may cause confusion if overused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The literal `0` is of type `int`.

A variable `auto avg = 0;` therefore has type `int`.

The literal `0.0` (or e.g. `3.14`) has type `double`, which is what you want.

---

As a general rule, use `auto` for a variable declaration where

- the type is explicitly specified in the initializer, or
- the type is awfully verbose, like some iterator type.

But don't use it without reason. :)

---

If for e.g. aesthetic reasons you want to keep `i` as an integer, then rewrite the computation

```
((i-1)/i)*avg + (*it)/i
```

to e.g.

```
((i-1)*avg + *it)/i
```

to avoid pure integer arithmetic for `(i-1)/i`.

Comment: A note: this alone does not correct the example code as `(i-1)/i` is still `0` so the recursive average is evaluated incorrectly.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. However, how does auto deal with differentiating between a float and double for example? Or an uint, int, or long?

Comment: @davidhigh, that's the case for i = 0, but not for i > 0.

Comment: @Teague: The same. It *does* do some type decay, for functions and arrays. And then you have to combine with e.g. `&` as reference type builder, if you want the result to be a reference to array.

Comment: @davidhigh: This answer is not about correcting the program logic, that's not asked for. Still, I fail to see what's wrong with the logic apart from incorrect types. In the first iteration the non-existent previous average should have weight 0. Disclaimer: it's late night here. Maybe I'm blind. :)